# SDL2 doesn't compile on macos Big Sur

Tags: objective-c, macos, cmake, sdl-2

In one of my projects I'm using git submodules to download the SDL2 Library and compile it. This is giving me a strange error so I tried to compile SDL2 Standalone and I got the same error.

I'm on a 13" MacBook Pro Big Sur

Steps to reproduce:

```
    git clone https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
    cd SDL
    cmake . -Bbuild
    make -C ./build
```

The error I get is

```
In file included from /Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/neural networks/libs/SDL/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m:24:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:91:143: error: function does not return NSString
- (NSAttributedString *)localizedAttributedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(nullable NSString *)value table:(nullable NSString *)tableName NS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(1) NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT API_AVAILABLE(macos(12.0), ios(15.0), watchos(8.0), tvos(15.0));
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                       ^                  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:103:48: note: expanded from macro 'NS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT'
        #define NS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(A) __attribute__ ((format_arg(A)))
                                                      ^          ~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libs/SDL/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libs/SDL/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The message would imply that Apple's own SDK files don't compile, but that can't be right. What's even stranger is that I'm using git submodules with SDL2 in another project but that compiles successfully and I can't find any discernible difference between this and the other project.

Edit:
I user `make -C ./build VERBOSE=1` to compare the output with the project that successfully compiled and the project that failed to compile.

Successfully compiled:

```
[  0%] Building C object libs/SDL/CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m.o
cd "/Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/Legion/build/libs/SDL" && /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -I"/Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/Legion/build/libs/SDL/include" -I"/Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/Legion/libs/SDL/include" -g -O3 -idirafter "/Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/Legion/libs/SDL/src/video/khronos" -D_THREAD_SAFE -msse3 -msse2 -msse -m3dnow -mmmx -Wshadow -fvisibility=hidden -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall  -fPIC -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks  -o CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m.o -c "/Users/<user>/Documents/side side projects/Legion/libs/SDL/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m"

Take note of: -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Failed to compile:

```
[  0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -DSDL2_EXPORTS -DUSING_GENERATED_CONFIG_H -I/Users/<user>/Desktop/SDL-main/build/include -I/Users/<user>/Desktop/SDL-main/include -idirafter "/Users/<user>/Desktop/SDL-main/src/video/khronos" -I/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.24/include/libusb-1.0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -msse3 -msse2 -msse -m3dnow -mmmx -Wshadow -fvisibility=hidden -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=11.5 -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m.o -c /Users/<user>/Desktop/SDL-main/src/file/cocoa/SDL_rwopsbundlesupport.m

Take note of: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the successfully compiled project and the project that failed to compile is the MacOS SDK version. The one that failed to compile used MacOS SDK 12 while the successful one used MacOS 11.3. Until this is fixed a temporary solution is to downgrade your MacOS SDK to 11.3.

Comment: I faced same error when trying to install node js module which built on c objective bindings. thanks bro, your answer is really helpful